# Remove "Cl." from file with bash without removing all Cl

Tags: sed, vim

I am trying to delete specifically  `Cl.` without deleting `Cl` inside a file:

```
Cl.CCC(N)(CC)C(=O)NC(CC(=O)O)c1ccccc1
CC(C)c1ncc(Cl)c(n1)C(=O)NCC(=O)O
```

And give me back this:

```
CCC(N)(CC)C(=O)NC(CC(=O)O)c1ccccc1
CC(C)c1ncc(Cl)c(n1)C(=O)NCC(=O)O
```

But everytime I tried with sed or vim it removes `Cl` as well. Someone knows any specific commando to delete it exactly `Cl.` and not `Cl`?

Thanks in advance.

Br
I have tried this among other....

```
sed 's/[Cl.]//g' 
sed 's/\Cl.//g'
```

Comment: is the `CL.` always at the beginning of the line? is that the only period (`.`) in the line?>

Comment: So, `sed 's/Cl\.//g' file > newfile`?

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: does the file contain other lines that a) don't contain a `CL.` or b) do contain `CL.` but should not be modified? if the answer is 'yes' to either then consider updating the question to show some additional lines (as well as updating the expected result)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```bash
sed 's/Cl\.//g' file > newfile
```

Here, `Cl\.` matches a `Cl.` substring.  See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/mq5rki):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='Cl.CCC(N)(CC)C(=O)NC(CC(=O)O)c1ccccc1
CC(C)c1ncc(Cl)c(n1)C(=O)NCC(=O)O'
sed 's/Cl\.//g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
CCC(N)(CC)C(=O)NC(CC(=O)O)c1ccccc1
CC(C)c1ncc(Cl)c(n1)C(=O)NCC(=O)O
```

Answer (score 4):

Substitution in `sed` uses regular expressions to find the bit to be replaced. Period `.` is a special character in a regular expression that matches any *single* character except line terminators: \n, \r, \u2028 or \u2029. So you need to escape the period with a back slash `\`:

```
sed 's/C1\.//g' input > output
```

Without escaping the period, `s/C1.//g` will match and remove all instances of `C` followed by `1` followed by any character (except line terminators).

As an aside, square brackets `[]`, also special characters, you used in your first attempt indicate a character class. So `[C1.]` will match the characters individually (any 'C', any '1', in this case any period).

Your second attempt escaped the `C` which is not a special character, so escaping has no effect.